# update solidity version in docker container

Tags: docker, solidity

I installed oyente using docker installation as described in the link

https://github.com/enzymefinance/oyente using the following command.
docker pull luongnguyen/oyente && docker run -i -t luongnguyen/oyente
I can analyse older smart contracts but I get compilation error when I try it on newer contracts. I need to update the version of solc but I couldn't.

On the container the current version is
solc, the solidity compiler commandline interface
Version: 0.4.21+commit.dfe3193c.Linux.g++ .

I read that the best way to update it is to use the command npm so I executed the following command but I am getting errors cause I assume npm version is not new also.

```
docker exec -i container_name bash -c "npm install -g solc"
```

I would appreciate, cause I am trying to sole this for hours now. Thanks in advance,
Ferda

Comment: `docker exec` probably isn't the right answer here; this will make a temporary change in your container that will get lost as soon as the container exits.  Can you edit the question to include a [mcve] with enough of your application's code to reproduce the issue?  If you update the `package.json` and `package-lock.json` files in your host development environment and rebuild the image, does that help?

Comment: Hi David can you write this as an answere so that I can accept it. This question still looks open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker's standard model is that an image is *immutable*: it contains a fixed version of your application and its dependencies, and if you need to update any of this, you need to build a new image and start a new container.

The first part of this, then, looks like any other Node package update.  [Install Node](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) in the unlikely event you don't have it on your host system.  Run `npm update --save solc` to install the newer version and update your `package.json` and `package-lock.json` files.  This is the same update you'd do if Docker weren't involved.

Then you can rebuild your Docker image with `docker build`.  This is the same command you ran to initially build the image.  Once you've created the new image, you can stop, delete, and recreate your container.

```bash
# If you don't already have Node, get it
# brew install nodejs

# Update the dependency
npm update --save solc
npm run test

# Rebuild the image
docker build -t image_name .

# Recreate the container
docker stop container_name
docker rm container_name
docker run -d --name container_name image_name

npm run integration
git add package*.json
git commit -m 'update solc version to 0.8.14'
```

Some common Docker/Node setups try to store the `node_modules` library tree in an anonymous volume.  This can't be easily updated, and hides the `node_modules` tree that gets built from the image.  If you have this setup (maybe in a Compose `volumes:` block) I'd recommend deleting any volumes or mounts that hide the image contents.

Note that this path doesn't use `docker exec` at all.  Think of this like getting a debugger inside your running process: it's very useful when you need it, but anything you do there will be lost as soon as the process or container exits, and it shouldn't be part of your normal operational toolkit.